# Algorithm for placing nodes in orbit around another

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to figure out what sort of equation would get me this.

If I have a center node, and an undetermined number of nodes orbiting it, how would I get the canvas coordinates I need to place them at even intervals?

In this case we have eight nodes because they were easiest for me to draw. But in other cases we could have more or less.

If you have a response in Java that would be best. Otherwise pseudocode is fine.

Sample image to help explain:

[image]

Comment: Oh, lord, physics! D:

Comment: Do you just want them placed around a circle?  Like at 0 degrees, 45 degrees, 90 degrees, etc.?

Comment: @Rubens rather geometry!

Answer (score 3):

If you travel from 0,0 to D,0 at an angle of 0 radians, at any other angle A you travel the following distance:

```
xdiff = D*cos(A)
ydiff = D*sin(A)
```

(note that A must be in radians - 0 and 2*pi are a full 0/360 degrees, so 2pi/2 is 180 degrees, 2pi/4 is 90 degrees and so on)

So (for example), to draw ten circles at a distance D around a central circle, consider each angle A = i*2pi/10, compute the xdiff and ydiff for each angle, add them to the central circle's position and draw the orbiting circle.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of approaches.

As a starting point take a look at
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing